# Requirejs with Backbonejs - "use strict" throw error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, strict

I am developing a application using Backbone.Marionette, I am loading the files using RequireJs, I decide to use the strict mode for my app, so I declared

"use strict" on the function. But I am getting error like this:

```
ught TypeError: Cannot set property 'App' of undefined
```

when i remove the "use strict" from function it all works fine.

here is my function:

```
define(["jQuery", "underscore", "backbone", "marionette","routes"], 
    function($, _, Backbone, Marionette, Routes){

        "use strict";

        console.log(Marionette);

        this.App = new Marionette.Application();

        this.App.addInitializer(function(){
            var Route = new Routes();
            Backbone.history.start();
        });

        this.App.start();


});
```

What is wrong here? how to fix this issue or how to apply strict mode to my function?

Comment: It looks like `this` is `undefined` when RequireJS calls the function. Try using `window.App`, or simply even `App` to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried calling App but not works. it works by calling windows.App; But i prefer to call whether App or this.App - how can i get that?

Comment: It would help to know your motive - Where do you want App to be accessible?

Comment: across the pages/files

Comment: You can return `App` as result of the module. That way, wherever you `require (['AppFile'], function (App) { ... });` App is accessible. Else, `window.App` is the same as `App` - `window` is the default global namespace. Try `App = App {};` your js file, before the `define` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add this to your main or config file you can then use the window as a dependency.

```
define('window',[],function(){return window;});
```